# .htaccess not redirect subdomain to root path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My root path is redirected automatically to another path like this

```
    http://www.example.com
```

goes to

```
    http://www.example.com/fr/home
```

i have put this in .htaccess at the racine of mywbesite

```
    RedirectMatch /$ /fr/home
```

My problem is that when i created a subdomain named

```
    booking.example.com
```

it is always redirected automatically to be like that

```
    booking.example.com/fr/home
```

how can i fix this to let only my subdomain point only to

```
    booking.example.com
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /fr/home [L,R]
```

Then test this in a separate browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Good my subdomain is no more reditrected to fr/home but it's not redirecting my home page to /fr/home

Comment: That is what this rule does. It redirects landing page to `/fr/home`. Do you have index.html or index.php in root also?

Comment: Did you change `example.com` with your actual domain name in this rule? Can you show your full .htaccess in question?